# Problem adding a nested MenuItem - nested items not showing

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, dotnetbar

I am trying to add nested (sub) menu items. The main menu items are showing but not the sub ones. Clearly I am missing a property, but can't figure it out. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Also tried adding the sub menu items to a ContextMenu then adding that to the MenuItem ContextMenu property, but that doesn't work either.

```
Private Function ReturnContexMenu() As ContextMenu
Try
    Dim FlagMI As New MenuItem
    With FlagMI
        .Header = "Quick Flag"
        .Name = "FlagMI"
    End With
    RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, FlagMI)

    Dim MarkReadMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkReadMI
        .Header = "Mark as read"
        .Name = "MarkReadMI"
    End With
    RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkReadMI)

    Dim MarkUnreadMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkUnreadMI
        .Header = "Mark as unread"
        .Name = "MarkUnreadMI"
    End With
    RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkUnreadMI)

    Dim MarkAsMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkAsMI
        .Header = "Mark as "
        .Items.Add(MarkReadMI)
        .Items.Add(MarkUnreadMI)
    End With

    Dim vMainContext As New ContextMenu
    With vMainContext
        .Name = "MainContextMenu"

        .Items.Add(FlagMI)
        .Items.Add(MarkAsMI)
    End With

    Return vMainContext
Catch ex As Exception
    EmailError(ex)
    Return Nothing
End Try
End Function
```

==========UPDATED==================

As you can see from the screenshot the sub menu items are not showing! Also tried this with a button and the same result. Could this be an issue with.NET 8? - Nope! Same problem with .NET 4.8 using a button.

[image: MenuItem]

Comment: There is no reason why the sub items won't show up - based on the posted code. Are you styling the menu?

Comment: Hi BionicCode - Not adding anything other than the defaults. It gets called directly to a DataGrid. How does one MenuItem know that it's the host for sub-menu items?

Comment: `MenuItem` is an `ItemsControl` (a `HeaderedItemsControl` to be precise). When you add items to its `ItemsSource` it will render them as nested items (based on the default template).

Comment: Then what is RegisterControl doing?

Comment: When I execute your code without RegisterControl it works for me.

Comment: RegisterControl registers the control to the grid - HoldingGrid.RegisterName(ControlType.Name.ToString, ControlType)

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the question

Comment: Do you add or use the items somewhere else? As I said, your problem is not reproducible with your currently posted code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by elsewhere. I use ContextMenu and MenuItem all over the place - this is the first time I have tried to nest them - and the desk is substantially harder than my head.  Thought it might be plain sailing after figuring out right click to select on a DataGrid. This IS the first time I have used ContextMenu on a DataGrid though!

Comment: By elsewhere I mean if you were using the same MenuItem instance at different places e.g. to add them to another menu. This would explain why it isn't visible. Soryy I'm afraid you won't find help. You can try to remove the RegisterControl method (although you say it only contains a single line of code). I have run your code and it works for me. You should create and post a complete minimal example that  reproduces the issue. Then we can review the posted snipet with more context.

Comment: Not using the same instance elsewhere. Removed RegisterControl, tried it with a button and tried it with a button in a .NET 4.8 app. Doesn't work at all - result is exactly the same as the screenshot. Sigh!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I can only repeat myself. Please, create an empty project and execute your posted code from the Loaded event handler to add the ContextMenu to the MainWindow and test it. This will work. Now continue to incrementally add the code necessary to reconstruct your final scenario. And test after each modification until you are able to reproduce it. Then post the code (chances are you will be able to identify the issue yourself this way as you should be able to identify the code that breaks the correct behavior).

Comment: I did as you suggested and it worked until I imported DevComponents WPF controls | Metro | Editors | Ribbon | Schedule, then it stopped working. I don't think DevComponents are even still in business now. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm happy you were able to figure out the mischief-maker. What are you using the library for? Does it have any relevant controls?

Comment: It has a load of controls - I'm trying to figure out if two of them are equivalent to MenuItem and Context menu - most start with 'Adv' and then a Windows control name - so far, no luck, it's just guesswork without documentation. Sadly, these controls are the base for hundreds of thousands of lines of code and starting again will not be a happy concept! Brandy is called for - the drink, not the stripper.

Comment: It can really backfire to depend on obsolete libraries. Maybe there is a naming conflict. Like fully qualifying the MenuItem and the ContextMenu may help. Or does the library also come with themes? Such a theme could mess with the MenuItem layout so that the child items are not rendered.

Comment: Maybe try to explicitly set `MenuItem.Style` to NULL. It's not unlikely that the 3rd party library defines an implicit Style for the MenuItem. For example, if they don't use nested menus then they could have simplified the ControlTemplate and removed the child items host. Setting a local value like NULL will prevent the implicit Style from being applied. Then give Brandy some good hugging and have a good time :D

Comment: You're a genius!!! Setting .Style = Nothing cured it. If you want to enter that as the answer I will mark it up! Thank you. Oh - how do I get the sub-menu to appear on the right? Currently it shows to the left of the main one.

Comment: The subitems are displayed in a `Popup`. The framework controls the placement. If there is not enough space to the right then it is displayed on the left side. You would have to override the template to change the placement behavior of the Popup. Alternatively, attach a Loaded event handler to the MenuItem and traverse the visual tree using the VisualTreeHelper to find the Popup element. The configure it. See [PlacementMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to learn about the placement options.

Comment: Maybe you should add a tag to your question because the problem is related to the library you are using. Is that DevExpress? You said DevComponents but is that from DevExpress?

Comment: Not DevExpress. Devcomponents DotNetBar - can't find any sign of them now, so I guess defunct.

Comment: On the issue of placement - currently it displays to the left of the ContextMenu unless the window is pushed up against the left of the screen, then it moves to the right (probably the reverse of the default). I have added a class for MenuItem and ContextMenu and added a dependency for MenuItem (Primatives.PlacementMode) - no matter what I set it to it still displays to the left. Shall I set this up as a separate question with code?

Comment: Yes, please. And create a minimal example that reproduces the placement issue - hopefully the Devcomponents library is not a player again and you can reproduce it without that dependency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78120737/menuitem-submenu-appearing-on-left-hand-side-of-contextmenu-instead-of-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring out that the issue disappears after removing the reference to a 3rd party control library, we can conclude that the library is changing the default layout by providing an implicit `Style`.
This `Style` seems to remove the items host for the child items, which is the reason that the subitems of the `MenuItem` are not rendered anymore.

Making use of the knowledge about the [dependency property precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list) we know we can prevent any implicit `Style` from being applied by setting a local value e.g. `null` or `Nothing`. This way the `MenuItem` is forced to use its default `Style`.

**VB.NET**

```vb
Private Function ReturnContexMenu() As ContextMenu
    Try
        Dim FlagMI As MenuItem = New MenuItem() With {
            .Style = Nothing
        }

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = FlagMI
            withBlock.Header = "Quick Flag"
            withBlock.Name = "FlagMI"
        End If

        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, FlagMI)
        Dim MarkReadMI As MenuItem = New MenuItem() With {
            .Style = Nothing
        }

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkReadMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as read"
            withBlock.Name = "MarkReadMI"
        End If

        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkReadMI)
        Dim MarkUnreadMI As MenuItem = New MenuItem() With {
            .Style = Nothing
        }

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkUnreadMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as unread"
            withBlock.Name = "MarkUnreadMI"
        End If

        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkUnreadMI)
        Dim MarkAsMI As MenuItem = New MenuItem() With {
            .Style = Nothing
        }

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkAsMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as "
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkReadMI)
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkUnreadMI)
        End If

        Dim vMainContext As ContextMenu = New ContextMenu()

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = vMainContext
            withBlock.Name = "MainContextMenu"
            withBlock.Items.Add(FlagMI)
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkAsMI)
        End If

        Return vMainContext
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

**C#**

```cs
private ContextMenu ReturnContexMenu()
{
    try
    {
        MenuItem FlagMI = new MenuItem() { Style = null };
        {
            var withBlock = FlagMI;
            withBlock.Header = "Quick Flag";
            withBlock.Name = "FlagMI";
        }
        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, FlagMI);

        MenuItem MarkReadMI = new MenuItem() { Style = null };
        {
            var withBlock = MarkReadMI;
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as read";
            withBlock.Name = "MarkReadMI";
        }
        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkReadMI);

        MenuItem MarkUnreadMI = new MenuItem() { Style = null };
        {
            var withBlock = MarkUnreadMI;
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as unread";
            withBlock.Name = "MarkUnreadMI";
        }
        RegisterControl(Inbox_Grid, MarkUnreadMI);

        MenuItem MarkAsMI = new MenuItem() { Style = null };
        {
            var withBlock = MarkAsMI;
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as ";
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkReadMI);
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkUnreadMI);
        }

        ContextMenu vMainContext = new ContextMenu();
        {
            var withBlock = vMainContext;
            withBlock.Name = "MainContextMenu";

            withBlock.Items.Add(FlagMI);
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkAsMI);
        }

        return vMainContext;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EmailError(ex);
        return null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */;
    }
}
```