# MenuItem SubMenu appearing on left hand side of ContextMenu instead of default

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

This question relates to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78112370/problem-adding-a-nested-menuitem-nested-items-not-showing) - the original question was resolved, but then another cropped up.

As you can see the MenuItem is appearing the wrong side

[image: ContextMenu (in app)]

As the prior issue was related to another control library I tested it with a minimal example...

[image: ContextMenu - Minimal]

Opened a new MVC project targeting .NET 8. Gave the grid on the MainWindow a name and then added a ToolBar with a button and a DataGrid. Applied the ContextMenu to each in turn and got the same behavior.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized

For i As Integer = 0 To 2
    Dim vRow As New RowDefinition
    If i = 1 Then
        vRow.Height = New GridLength(35, GridUnitType.Star)


    Else
        vRow.Height = New GridLength(35)
    End If
    TestGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(vRow)
Next

Dim vToolBar As New ToolBar
With vToolBar

End With
Grid.SetRow(vToolBar, 0)
TestGrid.Children.Add(vToolBar)

Dim vButton As New Button
With vButton
    .Content = "Test"
    .ContextMenu = ReturnContexMenu()
End With
vToolBar.Items.Add(vButton)

Dim vDG As New DataGrid
With vDG
    '  .ContextMenu = ReturnContexMenu()
End With
Grid.SetRow(vDG, 1)
TestGrid.Children.Add(vDG)

End Sub
```

...and this is the ContextMenu

```
Private Function ReturnContexMenu() As ContextMenu
Try
    Dim FlagMI As New MenuItem
    With FlagMI
        .Header = "Quick Flag"
        .Name = "FlagMI"
    End With

    Dim MarkReadMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkReadMI
        .Header = "Mark as read"
        .Name = "MarkReadMI"
    End With

    Dim MarkUnreadMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkUnreadMI
        .Header = "Mark as unread"
        .Name = "MarkUnreadMI"
    End With

    Dim MarkAsMI As New MenuItem
    With MarkAsMI
        .Header = "Mark as"
        .Items.Add(MarkReadMI)
        .Items.Add(MarkUnreadMI)
    End With

    Dim vMainContext As New ContextMenu
    With vMainContext
        .Name = "MainContextMenu"
        .Items.Add(FlagMI)
        .Items.Add(MarkAsMI)
    End With

    Return vMainContext
Catch ex As Exception

    Return Nothing
End Try
End Function
```

I have tried adding a class for MenuItem and adding the DependencyProperty of Primatives.PlacementMode and setting the default value to PlacementMode.Right - in fact I tried every setting, but it has no effect.

```
Public Class MIx
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem

Public Shared ReadOnly HoldingItem As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    name:="IsHoldingItem", propertyType:=GetType(Primitives.PlacementMode), ownerType:=GetType(MIx),
    typeMetadata:=New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue:=PlacementMode.Right))

Protected Overrides Sub OnInitialized(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInitialized(e)
    Style = Nothing



End Sub

Public Property IsHoldingItem As Primitives.PlacementMode
    Get
        Return GetValue(HoldingItem)
    End Get
    Set(value As Primitives.PlacementMode)
        SetValue(HoldingItem, value)
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

==========EDIT========

With a big thanks to @BionicCode for all his hard work, it now works

[image: ContextMenu working]

Just in case someone else runs into the same problem onApplyTemplate is...

```
 Public Overrides Sub onApplyTemplate()
 MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()
 Me.PART_Popup = TryCast(GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup"), Popup)
 If Not (Me.PART_Popup) Is Nothing Then
     Me.PART_Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = New CustomPopupPlacementCallback(AddressOf OnChildItemHostPlacementChanged)
     Me.PART_Popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom
 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not reproducible. However, I believe it can be fixed for your special scenario when you manually control the placement of the internal `Popup` by setting `Popup.Placement` to `PlacementMode.Custom`:

**PositionableMenuItem.vb**
We extend `MenuItem` to gracefully handle the custom positioning of the subitems.
The custom `PositionableMenuItem` retrieves its internal `Popup` and sets the `Popup.Placement` property to `PlacemmentMode.Custom`. This enables the `Popup` to invoke the `Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback` that we define in order to manually align the `Popup` (the sub-menu items).

Use the new `PositionableMenuItem.ChildPlacement` property to allow the client to select the position (currently only left, top, right and bottom are supported) - see example below.

```vb
Public Class PositionableMenuItem
    Inherits MenuItem

    Public Shared ReadOnly ChildPlacementProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ChildPlacement", 
        GetType(PlacementMode), 
        GetType(PositionableMenuItem), 
        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PlacementMode.Right))

    Public Property ChildPlacement As PlacementMode
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(ChildPlacementProperty), PlacementMode)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PlacementMode)
            Return SetValue(ChildPlacementProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property PART_Popup As Popup

    Public Overrides Sub onApplyTemplate()
      MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()
      Me.PART_Popup = TryCast(GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup"), Popup)
      If Not (Me.PART_Popup) Is Nothing Then
        Me.PART_Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = New CustomPopupPlacementCallback(AddressOf OnChildItemHostPlacementChanged)
        Me.PART_Popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Function OnChildItemHostPlacementChanged(ByVal popupSize As Size, ByVal targetSize As Size, ByVal offset As Point) As CustomPopupPlacement()
        Dim parent = CType(Me.Parent, Control)
        Dim parentPadding As Thickness = parent.Padding
        Dim additionalTargetWidth As Double = parentPadding.Left + parentPadding.Right + parent.BorderThickness.Right
        Dim additionalTargetHeight As Double = parentPadding.Top + parentPadding.Bottom + parent.BorderThickness.Bottom
        Dim horizontalOffset As Double = 0
        Dim verticalOffset As Double = 0

        Select Case Me.ChildPlacement
            Case PlacementMode.Bottom
                verticalOffset = targetSize.Height + additionalTargetHeight
                horizontalOffset -= parentPadding.Left
            Case PlacementMode.Right
                horizontalOffset = targetSize.Width + additionalTargetWidth
            Case PlacementMode.Left
                horizontalOffset -= popupSize.Width + parentPadding.Left
            Case PlacementMode.Top
                verticalOffset = -popupSize.Height
                horizontalOffset = -parentPadding.Left
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Select

        Dim location = New Point(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset)
        Dim primaryAxis As PopupPrimaryAxis = If(horizontalOffset > 0, PopupPrimaryAxis.Horizontal, PopupPrimaryAxis.Vertical)
        Dim placement = New CustomPopupPlacement(location, primaryAxis)
        Return {placement}
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInitialized(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnInitialized(e)
        Me.Style = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

### Usage example

You can use `PositionableMenuItem`to replace all `MenuItem` elements or only use it for those `MenuItem` elements that have child items.

```vb
Private Function ReturnContexMenu() As ContextMenu
    Try
        Dim FlagMI As MenuItem = New PositionableMenuItem()

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = FlagMI
            withBlock.Header = "Quick Flag"
            withBlock.Name = "FlagMI"
        End If

        Dim MarkReadMI As MenuItem = New PositionableMenuItem()

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkReadMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as read"
            withBlock.Name = "MarkReadMI"
        End If

        Dim MarkUnreadMI As MenuItem = New PositionableMenuItem()

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkUnreadMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as unread"
            withBlock.Name = "MarkUnreadMI"
        End If

        Dim MarkAsMI As MenuItem = New PositionableMenuItem() With {
            .ChildPlacement = PlacementMode.Right
        }

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = MarkAsMI
            withBlock.Header = "Mark as"
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkReadMI)
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkUnreadMI)
        End If

        Dim vMainContext As ContextMenu = New ContextMenu()

        If True Then
            Dim withBlock = vMainContext
            withBlock.Name = "MainContextMenu"
            withBlock.Items.Add(MarkAsMI)
            withBlock.Items.Add(FlagMI)
        End If

        Return vMainContext
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: You've done a lot of work there! Thank you very much. Just having an issue with onApplyTemplate 'If TypeOf Me.PART_Popup Is [not] Then Nothing' and 'Me.PART_Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback += AddressOf OnChildItemHostPlacementChanged', the latter I think should be AddHandler object.action, addressof?

Comment: Yes, correct. I was converting from C# to VB.NET and the converters fail to convert this syntax most of the time.

Comment: Now working - if I could mark it up a thousand times I would. I added the correct code for onApplyTemplate to the bottom of my question. Thank you again. I would have spent months trying to figure that one out :-)

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. I'm happy I could help. You said you posted the correct code in your question. Was my override not working or compiling? Mybe something went lost during conversion? I mean you also need the computations, right? Your update looks like you were only missing the override? Or did I miss something?  ;)

Comment: It was just the code converter messed up with onApplyTemplate. On the chance that someone else has the same problem I thought I would just add that. When you couldn't reproduce the issue did you use VB.NET with .NET 8? It could be a bug in VB if you used C# and then translated it back it wouldn't have come to light.

Comment: Ok, then I will copy your version and add it to my answer. I was using C# and .NET 8. But the code is so trivial I really think it must be related to your environment. It's definitely not language related as this would mean a compiler bug. Again, the code is too trivial. Simple instantiation and some assignments.

Comment: It's strange that I start a new project, add a toolbar and DataGrid and then run the code against it - nothing else in the environment and it opened it to the left. VB is all I can think of. VB does have some quirks to be sure - MS are not in a rush to keep it up to date.